# all points y value undefined! error in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

i'm trying to plot the following formula using gnuplot, but i get an error message says "all points y value undefined!", what is the problem and what can i do to solve it?

Here is the code:

```
gnuplot> i = {0.0,1.0}                              
gnuplot>  plot [y=1:100] 1 + (0. + 0.2440625921544017*i)*(0.9680598247711271/y**5 + 0.4600760626004062/y**4 + 0.31009952311074734/y**3 + 0.3289857649601461/y**2 + 0.7029129290126906/y)
```

Where i is the complex number (Sqrt[-1]).

Comment: Seems that your code is not formatted. Edit your question.

Comment: @MichaelO. i edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly plot a function with complex values. You must decide which parts of the function you want to plot, use e.g. `abs()`, `imag()` or `real()`:

```
i = {0.0, 1.0}
f(x) = 1 + (0. + 0.2440625921544017*i)*(0.9680598247711271/x**5 + 0.4600760626004062/x**4 + 0.31009952311074734/x**3 + 0.3289857649601461/x**2 + 0.7029129290126906/x)

set xrange [1:10]
plot abs(f(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Also helpful is to use `arg()` for the phase/angle of the complex value, see `help arg`.